# A SUMIFS() #VALUE! error occurs when I am trying to compare a named range of MONTH() values to a MONTH() value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, named-ranges

Consider the following table

[image]

Cells `C3:D7` are formatted as `[hh]:mm "h"`.

I would now like to add up all September values by writing

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$7, Month_of_the_Day, MONTH($B3))
```

in cell `D3` but then all of these `#VALUE!` errors appear. The same is true if I try to replace `MONTH($B3)` by `MONTH($B4)`.

`Month_of_the_Day` is a named range that contains the following:

```
=MONTH(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$7)
```

Why does this `#VALUE!` error occur all the time when I just want to add up all the working hours of September or October?

Comment: The criteria ranges used by SUMIFS (and other ..IF/IFS functions) must be **ranges**, not arrays. `=MONTH(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$7)` returns an array of values, hence the error.

Comment: Ok, I see. So, how can I fix the error and compare ranges to each other?

Comment: Use Bookend the dates:  `=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$7,$B$3:$B$7,">=" & EOMONTH($B3,-1)+1,B$3:$B$7,"<" & EOMONTH($B3,0)+1)`

Comment: Or use `SUMPRODUCT` instead: `=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$C$7,--(Month_of_the_Day=MONTH($B3)))`